# Create table schema to read data in hive table partitioned by country and bucketed by year?

Tags: mysql, hive

| Index | company | location | dates | job-title | summary | pros | cons | overall-ratings | work-balance-stars | culture-values-stars | carrer-opportunities-stars | comp-benefit-stars | senior-management-stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | google | none | Dec 11; 2018 | Current Employee - Anonymous Employee | Best Company to work for | People are smart and friendly | Bureaucracy is slowing things down | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 5 |

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reviews.dp_review_data (
  Index INT,
  company STRING,
  location map<STRING,STRING>,
  dates map<STRING,STRING>,
  `job-title` STRING,
  summary STRING,
  pros STRING,
  cons STRING,
  `overall-ratings` INT,
  `work-balance-stars` INT,
  `culture-values-stars` INT,
  `carrer-opportunities-stars` INT,
  `comp-benefit-stars` INT,
  `senior-management-stars` INT)
partitioned by (location[1] string)
clustered by (dates[1]) into 2 buckets
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
map keys terminated by ';'
LOCATION 'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/faizalnajeeb761@gmail.com/Review';
```

I have tried above SQL command but confusion how do I use complex datatype to create partitions and buckets

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother.

Seriously, most `PARTITIONing` fails to provide any performance benefit.  In some cases, Partitioning slows down queries.  Think of it this way -- While "partition pruning" sounds great, it is generally no better (sometimes worse) than using a composite index.

Please provide the main `SELECTs` that you expect to use on the table; I will discuss the optimal indexing with partitioning versus without.

**Summary table**

This *might* be applicable:

```
CREATE TABLE summary (
    company ...,
    dy DATE NOT NULL,    -- assuming there are many entries per day
    ct ...,   -- COUNT(*) for each day for each company
    `sum_overall-ratings`  INT,
    `sum_work-balance-stars`  INT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (company, dy)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then if you augment this table at the time new rows come into the main table (or do it each night for the whole day), you can very efficiently do this (for last year's averages):

```
SELECT  company,
        SUM(`sum_overall-ratings` / SUM(ct)) AS 'avg-rating',
        SUM( ...
    FROM summary
    GROUP BY company
    WHERE dy >= '2021-01-01'
      AND dy  < '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: select company,
  avg(`overall-ratings`),
  avg(`work-balance-stars` ), 
  avg(`culture-values-stars`), 
  avg(`carrer-opportunities-stars`), 
  avg(`comp-benefit-stars` ), 
  avg(`senior-management-stars`)
from reviews.dp_review_data
group by company;

Comment: @Faisal - That query has to read each and every row of the data once, whether they are all in a single table or scattered among partitions (or even scattered among tables).  Reading rows is the most costly part of most queries.  Furthermore, no index will be useful.  I suggest you try the table with and without partitioning once you have enough data to be worth measuring.

Comment: @Faisal - I added a tailored example of summary tables.